# display status report even though the module is disabled

Tags: hooks, log-messages

I want to execute some code in my custom module to display status reports even though my custom module is disabled.

`hook_requirements()` can be used to display status reports, but it only works when the module is enabled. I want this to work even when the module is disabled.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

That's not possible.

For hooks to be executed, your module **must** be enabled. From [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7):

> To extend Drupal, a module need simply implement a hook. When Drupal wishes to allow intervention from modules, it determines which modules implement a hook and calls that hook in **all enabled modules** that implement it.

Emphasis mine.

Allowing modules to run code even when they're not enabled would be a massive security risk, and could cause all sorts of other unforeseen problems.

Comment: Hint for OP: You can always split your module, and keep the reporting part in the one you will keep enabled.

Comment: @molot thanks for your suggestion. Is it possible to auto enable the module which will display status reports when the site is moved from production to development server?

Comment: @GanesanGopal it's possible to do pretty much anything in your migration scripts.